# Glympse - How to use Private Groups in a Favorites

Tags: glympse

How can I use a private group when defining a new favorite? When selecting a recipient for a favorite glympse only lets me select individuals. The does not appear to be any way to select private group.

Answer (score 0):

Glympse Private Groups are a relatively new feature to the app and there is not currently a way to add private groups to a favorite. Note that you can set the favorite places "Home" and "Work" from the Glympse Settings, and these destinations will be available when creating a new Glympse within a private group. This can be used as a partial work-around until this feature is added.